# WCF Endpoint. Multiple Clients

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have an IIS hosted WCF webservice. It started with two consumers.

1) A WinForm test harness in the same solution to test the WCF contracts in the IDE.

2) An Asp.Net Web App that is consuming the published version.

All was working out of the box so to speak.

Then along came the 3rd consumer, an Android app. To get this consuming correctly had to decorate the WCF contracts with JSON WebGets and Webinvokes and alter the WCF Web.config to suit.

Now the original two consumers no longer work. So I need to alter Web.config and / or App.configs to get a configuration where all three work.

Focusing on the IDE first. I have the following service model section for the WCF service Web.Config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="JsonBinding"
              contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService" name="Json" 
              kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
      <identity>
        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8707/CouponParking.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_ICouponService" />
  </client>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttp" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="JsonBinding" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="CouponParkingWCF.CouponService">
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="" name="jsonEndPoint"
                contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>    
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

The WinForm Test harness App.config has:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttp" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8707/CouponParking.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttp" 
              contract="CouponParking.ICouponService"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_ICouponService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am not experienced at configuring endpoints and the above has been based on examples and guesswork.

When I run the Test Harness the wcf Client instantiates but a call on a contract fails with :

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8707/CouponParking.svc 
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."
```

The inner exception is :

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}
[System.Net.WebException]: {"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HelpLink: null
HResult: -2146233079
InnerException: null
Message: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
Source: "System"
StackTrace: "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)"
TargetSite: {System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse()}
```

I would appreciate some guidance on what I have got wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to expose the same service to different clients (with different needs - i.e., bindings) on the same endpoint?  If so, you can't do that.  You'll need to expose different endpoints for the different implementations of the service.

Comment: Also, could you post the config files as they were *before* you added the third client?  It might help to see what it was when it was working, as well as what it is now (when it's not working).

Comment: Each server-side endpoint has **one binding defined** - e.g. you **cannot** have a single endpoint that supports both your `basicHttpBinding` (SOAP) for your first and second client, and at the same time also support `webHttpBinding` (REST) for the Android client. You'll need to use **two separate endpoints** for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a glance, it appears that you've mixed up client endpoints with service endpoints in your service's config file.  There's no reason for client endpoints to appear in the **service's** config file, unless that service is itself calling another service.

Your WinForm's config file is defining a client with `basicHttpBinding`, but you do not expose a **service** endpoint with `BasicHttpBinding`, which is most likely the reason for the error you're getting.

I would try deleting the client endpoints in your service's config file, and add them to the `<services>` section, like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttp" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="JsonBinding" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="CouponParkingWCF.CouponService">
      <endpoint address="SOAP"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ICouponService" />
      <endpoint address="JSON"
                binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="JsonBinding"
                contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService" name="Json" 
                kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
        <identity>
          <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
```

Remember the ABC's of WCF: **A** = Address, **B** = Binding and **C** = Contract - those three items define a service.

Since you added a client that needed a different binding then your test harness or your ASP.NET application, you need to expose a second endpoint with that binding.

**EDITED**

As @marc_s pointed out, you'll need two distinct relative addresses.  I've updated the config file to reflect that.

I've not had an occasion to use multiple endpoints myself, but I *believe* you'd use them this way, with the base address being provided by the location of the *.svc file:

```
http://localhost:8707/CouponParking.svc/SOAP
http://localhost:8707/CouponParking.svc/JSON
```

With the first being for the `BasicHttpBinding` and the second being for the `WebHttpBinding`.

Comment: You'd have to provide two distinct addresses for these two endpoints you're defining. Their "base" address is defined by the IIS virtual directory and location of the `*.svc` file - and now you'll need two distinct relative addresses on that to distinguish the two endpoints....

Comment: @marc_s - Thanks.  I've updated my answer to reflect my understanding of what you said.  If it's still in error let me know.

Comment: Thanks Tim, both you and marc_s provided not only the solution but a clear explanation. Your answer precedes marc_s so I have marked you as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You basically just need **two separate endpoints** to provide both the `basicHttpBinding` (a SOAP binding) and the `webHttpBinding` for your Android client (a REST binding).

The "base" address of your service is defined by your IIS virtual directory and where the `*.svc` file lives (`http://localhost:8707/CouponParking.svc`) - so both services will be reachable at this "base" address plus any relative address defined

So you need to configure this something like this:

```
<services>
   <service name="CouponParkingWCF.CouponService">
      <!-- define the basicHttp (SOAP) endpoint at the base address -->
      <endpoint name="SoapEndpoint"
          address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService" />
      <!-- define the REST endpoint at (base)+"/rest" -->
      <endpoint name="RestEndpoint"
          address="rest"
          behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" 
          binding="webHttpBinding" 
          contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService" />
   </service>
</services>
```

With this setup, you should be able to call your service using the `basicHttpBinding` (SOAP) at

```
http://yourServer:8707/CouponParking.svc
```

and you should be able to access the REST-based, JSON-enabled endpoint at

```
http://yourServer:8707/CouponParking.svc/rest
```

Both server-side endpoints will be handled by the same service code - it's just the endpoint (and the protocols that endpoints understands) that are different

Comment: Both you and Tim are right on the money. I have marked Tim's as answer as his  was first. My thanks for not only the solution but the explanation.